# Excel VBA ADO recordset issue with Null values

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I'm pretty new at VBA and having an issue with ADO.
 
Currently the code im using returns fields (**Name**, **Suburb**, **State**) from a SQL database into a ListBox.
The code works fine as long as there are there all fields have a value, if there is a Null value it returns the error

> Could not set the List property. Type mismatch

I need to find a way so if the Suburb and/or State fields return a Null value that it still populates the Listbox.
Any info would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

#### Database entries

[image: Database entries]

#### Screenshot of error

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLquery As String
Dim cnnstr As String
Dim SQLName As String
Dim i As Integer

SQLName = "Salon"
SQLquery = "SELECT [Name], [Suburb], [State] FROM Salon WHERE Name like '" & SQLName & "%'"

Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
                "Data Source=localhost; " & _
                "Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;" & _
                "User ID=sa;" & _
                "Password=Password;" & _
                "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

cnn.Open cnnstr  
cnn.Execute SQLquery
rs.Open SQLquery, cnn, adOpenStatic

    rs.MoveFirst
    i = 0
    With Me.lb_search
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = rs!Name
            .List(i, 1) = rs!Suburb
            .List(i, 2) = rs!State
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop Until rs.EOF
    End With

btn_search_test_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rs.Close
cnn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Comment: `.List(i, 1) = rs!Suburb & ""` is kind of hacky, but typically works.

Comment: `SELECT [Name], NVL([Suburb], '') as Suburb, NVL([State], '') as State FROM Salon WHERE...` should also work

Answer (score 0):

`Iif` can return an alternate for Null Values.

For example:

```
.List(i, 0) = IIf(IsNull(a), "(not found)", rs!Name)
```

will return "(not found)" if the value is null.

More info [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) and [here](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=139335).

Comment: Isn't `nz` an Access function?

Comment: @Tim -- oops - I misread (and always forget `nz` is annoyingly not-available in Excel!)  I've corrected my answer to apply to Excel VBA, thanks!

Comment: This is sad. What if it is a date, then you have to convert everything to string in Excel and Excel won't treat it as a date. Not that it handles dates much better.

Answer (score 0):

*nz is annoyingly not-available in Excel*
Oh yes it is :-)

```
Public Function NZ(v As Variant, Optional valueifnull As Variant = 0) As Variant
If IsNull(v) Then
      NZ = valueifnull
Else
    NZ = v
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Of all the websites I have looked at over several hours, this is the cleanest and most simple solution.  The hours of searching will etch one thing clearly in my mind.  Even if Excel developers didn't see fit to include a function, I must REMEMBER that I can create my own.  Thanks @Harassed Dad.